# No matter what I try, I cannot get this application to match all different device sizes, any suggestions on how to use constraints like this?

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints

I have now spent about eight hours messing with constraints, watching videos, reading tutorials on class sizes, etc. Nothing I do will get my application to look right on differently sized devices. It would be so simple if I could just select the device I wanted, structure the app correctly, and apply it, but sadly that's just not possible.

[image: Image of my application]

Answer (score 1):

If you want the labels equally spaced, independent of screen height (with different amounts of spacing), there are three possibilities:

One, create four invisible views, put them in the spaces between the labels, and add three constraints that their heights are equal. If you don't want equal distances, you can set for example height of gap 1 = height of gap 2 times 0.5; just an example.

Two, set the top of a label to the height of a few, multiplied by some multiplier. In interface builder, you have to create the constraint, then double-click and you can change the multiplier field.

Three, have constraints for the distance between labels, make them IBOutlets, and in viewDidLoad you calculate the proper distances and set constraint.constant = .... That's what I usually do if I need to make some changes for the iPhone 4 with smaller screen.

Answer (score 0):

I`d start in the middle of your view:

Label(blue) - center horizontally+vertically, leading + trailing

Label(brown,green) - leading + trailing to container, vertical spacing to Label(blue)

Label(light green) - center horizontally, spacing to bottom layout

ADBannerView - center horizontally, bottom space to bottom layout

Button - center horizontally, spacing to ADBannerView

Try it and customize to your needs.